# Why do they loop on route parameters in this Angular tutorial?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I was looking through the [Angular 2 tutorial about routing](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html). At some point they add a route `/detail/:id` and add an `ngOnInit()` method to handle this route and, in particular, to get the `:id` parameter:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
    let id = +params['id'];
    this.heroService.getHero(id)
      .then(hero => this.hero = hero);
  });
}
```

The part I don't understand is why are they looping on route parameters? Since there can be only one ID, isn't it possible to get it using `this.route.params['id']`?

Also, if really there was multiple ids, what would the point of looping on them since each new hero would only replace the previous one?

Comment: I don't think it loops through params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the route is changed in a way that only parameters change (for example `id` in `/somepath/:id/otherPath`) then the router doesn't navigate away and back to the same component but instead keeps the same component and emits a parameter change event.

For each event `(params:Params) => { ... }` is executed.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve single **Id** you can also use this,

```
let id = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Now you can do it like this:
First import switchMap from rxjs

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
```

then

```
this.route.params
    .switchMap((params: Params) => this.heroService.getHero(+params['id']))
    .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the forEach() method which you are using here is not Array.prototype.forEach() rather its Rx.Observable.prototype.forEach().

Angular 2 route.params - gives an array of Observable. Invoking forEach() on the this array with a lambda is same as calling subscribe to each parameters.

Further the reason behind subscribing to the params is that ngOnInit() is invoked when a component is routed from other component or refreshed. If the value in the parameter is used not subscribed, it will not work if you are routing to the same component with different values of the parameters as ngOnInit does not get invoked in that case.

Please refer to 
[the Rx.Observable.prototype.forEach](http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/subscribe.html)

Answer (score 0):

You probably know this already now but I think the concept you need to get is that params is not an array, it's an Observable.

```
console.log(this.route.params['id']); // undefined
this.route.params.forEach(x => console.log(x['id'])); // the id e.g 999
```

As others have mentioned there are various ways to get the id just be careful when using snapshot as it will not update when components are reused.